# retrofit2 errorbody.content is not accessible

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new in retrofit2 world, currently I have a problem on getting errorbody from `onNext`.

Here is my sample code :

```
 public void onNext(Response<LoginResponse> value) {
      ResponseBody responseBody = value.errorBody();
      String sam = responseBody.toString();
 }
```

My issue is, I cant get the errorbody().content. It is like it is not accessible.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218#issuecomment-149885896

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
String errorBody =  value.errorBody().string;
```

or

```
String errorBody =  value.errorBody().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit's error bodys are of type OkHttp3 `ResponseBody`. This class is abstract and its implementations define different ways the content is represented internally.

There are different ways you can get the content. You can get it in `bytes`, as a string, or even get an `InputStream` for it - check them out [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html).

I suppose an easy way is to use `string()`:

```
value.errorBody().string();
```

Note that these methods usually read the response from a buffer, which means that if I recall correctly, calling again `string()` would not give you the content of the response again. In particular, `string()` also reads the entire body into memory, which may cause an out of memory exception.

After you have the content, if you want it as an object from your data model, you'll have to deserialize it manually. There are numerous ways to do this and it's easy to find on the web, but for sake of completeness, here's a way to do it with `gson`:

```
String error = value.errorBody().string();
MyPojo pojo = new Gson().fromJson(error, MyPojo.class);
```

*(here `MyPojo` would be your error class representing the error)*

Answer (score 0):

You can't get errorBody without http-error code.
Use smt like this:

```
if (!value.isSuccessful && value.errorBody() != null) {
    val errorBodyText = value.errorBody()?.string()?:""
    val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson<ErrorObject>(errorBodyText, ErrorObject::class.java)
}
```